# correct output after reading csv file - fread() vs read.csv.raw (iotools package)

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread

I am testing 'read.csv.raw' and 'fread' -  'fread' appears to read data incorrectly. I need some guidance why it is happening. So far I have not found the clear answer about this issue.

My script is as follows:

```
library(iotools)
library(data.table)

#make a dataframe
df_size<-100
n<-data.frame(x=1:df_size,y=rnorm(1:df_size),z=rnorm(1:df_size),w=c("fgdfgd"))
n[,4]<-as.character(n[,4])

file_output<-"test.csv"
check<-n
#to save the dataframe to the csv file 
if (file.exists(file_output)) file.remove(file_output)
cat(noquote(paste(paste(names(check),collapse = ";"),"\n")),file = file_output)
system.time(write.csv.raw(check,file_output,sep=";",append=TRUE))

#reading1
system.time(check<-read.csv.raw(file_output,header=TRUE,sep=";"))
str(check)

#reading2
system.time(check<-fread(file_output,sep=";", data.table = FALSE
                          ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE
                          ,dec=".")
            )
str(check)
```

The reading1 is Ok but the output of the reading2 is queer (not a dataframe but a kind of list).
*I have no a clue why it is happening*

Formats and data structure of the source file seems to be ok (checked by Notepad++).

## UPDATE of 12/03/16:

It looks like that 'fread' and 'read.csv.raw' use different file formats to generate the correct output. It cause the:

1. 'fread' deals with files generated by 'write.csv' or 'write.table' (sample of the format is below). It could cuase the incompaitability of two function concerning correct reading of the input data:

> "x";"y";"z";"w" \r\n
> 1;2,19881034888372;-0,76140845752573;"fgdfgd" \r\n
> 2;1,31241297643351;-1,10813097991471;"fgdfgd" \r\n
> 3;-0,265145056696353;0,167098566457511;"fgdfgd" \r\n
> 4;0,54319405923209;1,43792266965061;"fgdfgd" \r\n

2. 'read.csv.raw' deals with files generated by 'write.csv.raw'(sample of the format is below):

> x;y;z;w  \r\n
> 1;2.19881034888372;-0.76140845752573;fgdfgd \n
> 2;1.31241297643351;-1.10813097991471;fgdfgd \n
> 3;-0.265145056696353;0.167098566457511;fgdfgd \n
> 4;0.54319405923209;1.43792266965061;fgdfgd \n
> 5;-0.41433994791886;0.62409900226019;fgdfgd \n
> 6;-0.476246894615578;0.781638996872154;fgdfgd \n

Comment: `fread` gives a warning after running this code; maybe start there.

Comment: @Dimon D. I ran your code and did not get any warning or error.

Comment: Weird. It also works if the text is read directly, instead of from file: `fread("x;y;z;w \n1;-0.442334234968453;-0.503772209108539;fgdfgd\n2;0.139866320811732;-0.214465613009523;fgdfgd", sep=";")` (on data.table 1.9.7, r 3.2.3)

Comment: Think I found it. Examine `rawdat = readChar(file_output, file.info(file_output)$size)` and note that your first newline is written as `\r\n` while the next one is written as `\n` (contrary to the excerpt in my last comment).

Comment: @Frank
Well, I see the case about "\r". 
But I dont know how to handle it in correct way. As I understand, write.csv.raw makes a header through "\r\n".
I would be very grateful to help to solve the issue.

Comment: Ok. You could post a feature request for ingestion of mixed-line-ending-format files, though I don't think they're common in practice. In any case, it should be possible to take `fread("test.csv", nrows=0)` and `fread("test.csv", skip=1)` and bind them together (but it isn't... arguably a bug). By the way, use the verbose option, like `fread("test.csv", verbose=TRUE)` for more details on the problem.

Comment: @Frank, thanks for the ping. There's an issue filed already: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1183

Comment: @Frank
Thanks for your last comment about fread application (header + body). However your approach generate the same discrepancy. I need to convert the file rows from unix to window format somehow. It is likely the case. I would be greatful for the working example.